# How can I rotate the camera around the player on the Y axis on this code in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, rotate

I have a problem, I want my camera to rotate along the Y axis while he is looking at the player with an offset. I want to rotate with Q and E key to right and left around the player but on my Camera Follow Player Script I used Vector3.SmoothDamp to follow the player on the other side when I try to rotate with Keys with transform.RotateAround() it seems like its locked on the Y axis I dont know how to get around this.

Code:

---

```
void CameraFollowPlayer()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + offset, 
                                             ref velocity, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.LookAt(player.position);
}

void RotateRightLeft () 
{
    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, transform.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, -transform.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is because the axis you are passing on **RotateAround** is your local up (**transform.up**). You should use **Vector3.Up** instead if you want to do it on world coordinates, or **target's transform.up** if you want to rotate around the target's local up normal.

About the offset, you should consider getting a direction vector pointing towards the target, the basic formula is:

> **d = target - observer**

Having that vector, you'll have to normalize it (convert it to a Vector with magnitude of 1) to then multiply it by the desired offset, and finally is just up to assign the camera's position to the target's plus the offset.

A quick example code would be like this:

```
public class CameraExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float offset;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        // Follow target at offset:
        transform.position = ((target.position - transform.position).normalized * offset + target.position);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime)); // Or transform.up, as I've suggested
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, -(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a target position (a separate transform or Vector3) that rotates at a fixed distance around the player as controlled by key input, then use the SmoothDamp to make the camera gravitate towards that point.